# Proper way to store and pass data between classes

Tags: ios, arrays, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have a Users class and Login class (in separate files) where data is initialised and obtained first in the Login class and then stored in the Users class for future use in other classes.  To make use of the variables from the Users class, it appears that I have to constantly initialise it which resets the values in the class. How can I obtain variables without constantly initialising?

**What it is right now:**

Data is received in Login.swift -> Data is passed to Users.swift -> Unable to display data stored in Users.swift in ViewController.swift

**What I am looking for:**

Data is received in Login.swift -> Data is passed to Users.swift -> Display data stored in Users.swift in ViewController.swift

**Code in ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!

// var usernameLabelText = String()

let dataObj = Users(Name: "", Email: "", Id: "", ProfilePicture: "", Username: "")

var usernameLabelText: String? {
    return String(dataObj!.username)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    usernameLabel.text = "Welcome \(usernameLabelText)"
    print("This is the \(dataObj!.username)")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

**Code in Login.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
class Login {

var userName:String!
var passWord:String!

init(userName : String, passWord : String) {

    let parameters = [
        "username": userName,
        "password": passWord 
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://anyapi.com", parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.data)
            print(response.result)
            if let result = response.result.value {
                print("Did receive JSON data: \(result)")
                let value = JSON(result)
                if let api_key = value["api_token"].string {
                    print("The token is " + api_key)
                } else{
                    print("error parsing api token")
                }
             //pass data to Users class
               _ = Users.init(Name: value["name"].string, Email: value["email"].string, Id: value["id"].string, ProfilePicture: value["profile_picture"].string, Username: value["username"].string)
            }
            else {
                print("JSON data is nil.")
            }


    }

}
}
```

**Code in Users.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class Users {
private var _name: String!
private var _email: String!
private var _userId: String!
private var _profilePicture: String!
private var _username: String!

var particulars: [String] = []

var name: String {
    _name = particulars[0]
    return _name
}

var email: String {
    _email = particulars[1]
    return _email
}

var userId: String {
    _userId = particulars[2]
    return _userId
}

var profilePicture: String {
    _profilePicture = particulars[3]
    return _profilePicture
}

var username: String {
      _username = particulars[4]
    return _username
}


required init?(Name: String?, Email: String?, Id: String?, ProfilePicture: String?, Username: String?) {
    particulars += ["\(Name)"]
    particulars += ["\(Email)"]
    particulars += ["\(Id)"]
    particulars += ["\(ProfilePicture)"]
    particulars += ["\(Username)"]
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a User type variable in View Controller.

   ```
   var usrData : Users?
   ```
2. When you instantiate the View Controller, assign the variable to the already initialised User Class.

   ```
   let view_controller_to_present = blahblah as! View Controller;<br>
   view_controller_to_present.usrData = DataFromRequest;<br>
   presentViewController(_ viewControllerToPresent: view_controller_to_present,animated flag: true, completion completion: nil);
   ```
3. Access the data.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to say...

About storage :
Your data haven't been stored yet. You can use Core Data to persist them or NSUserDefault for a lighter solution (the latter won't persist data after app killing), or even files.

About passing data from one view to another :
You could override prepareForSegue function, or use protocol and delegate pattern.